# $.ajax() printing an array of jsonObjects not getting printed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an array of json Objects that are to be retrieved by $.ajax() and printed in a table. But, I cannot print though they are getting retrieved by Webpage through XAMPP (Seen in Network >> xhr). Can someone help?

JSON:

```
{"people":[
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"De'Souza","blogURL":"www.google.com"},
    {"firstName":"Romeo","lastName":"Cherolov","blogURL":"www.google.com"},
    {"firstName":"Caspian","lastName":"Monovola","blogURL":"www.google.com"}
    {"firstName":"Sita","lastName":"Martin","blogURL":"www.google.com"}
    {"firstName":"Rina","lastName":"Schenoi","blogURL":"www.google.com"}
]}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/example4/data.json',
      data: { patientID: "1" },
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(jsonData) {

            for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                console.log(jsonData[i].firstName);
            }

      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Some Error');
      }
});
```

It is just throwing the Error Alert, though in Network >> xhr I can see the 'people - array of json objects' being fetched. Pls help!

Comment: joyBlanks' answer is correct. `jsonData.people` is the array of people, not `jsonData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `console.log(jsonData.people[i].firstName);`

Comment: Bro. It wont matter as people is saved as jsonData while in response. Also, did it with Error alert throwing up.

Comment: error: function(e) {
        alert('Some Error' + json.stringify(e));
      }
Please tell us exact error

Comment: In alert "Some Error" - as you can see in Code. (Otherwise no error in console).

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: Peterson bro it does matter, people array is in an object. Consider you have another array `people1` in root object how will you access it then.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your loop as

```
foreach(jsonData.people as val)
 {
       console.log(val['firstName']);
 }
```

Comment: Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Is this supposed to be JS? Because if so, this is not valid JS.